# Sorting a dictionary by keys no longer shows the values

Tags: python, django

I have this dictionary:

```
analytics = {
   datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0):{
        'clicks': 5049,
        'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0)
   },
   datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0): {
        'clicks': 592, 
        'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)
   },
   datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0): {
        'impressions': 2159, 'clicks': 223,
        'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0)
   },
   datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0): {
        'impressions': 32747, 
        'clicks': 4184, 
        'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)
   }
}
```

I want to sort it by date, which I do using:

`analytics = sorted(analytics, key=lambda k: k)`

However, while this does sort the dictionary, it removes everything except the key. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: You could do `sorted(analytics.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])`, but dictionaries in Python < 3.6 are unordered

Comment: I want to show the dictionary ordered by month - so the data with March then April then May then June. So I can show it in that order in a template.

Comment: Then don't use a dictionary, use a list.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries aren't orderable. When you call `sorted` on a dictionary it treats it as an iterable, which it produces by key only. You can test this with:

```
for k in some_dict:
    print(k)  # should produce each key
```

What you want instead is to sort `dict.items`, which is still not a dict, but instead more like a list of `(key, value)` tuples

```
analytics = sorted(analytics.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are ordered since 3.6 (implementation detail), and since 3.7 by spec, so you can do this:

```
>>> {k: analytics[k] for k in sorted(analytics)}
{datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0): {'clicks': 592, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)}, datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0): {'clicks': 5049, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0)}, datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0): {'impressions': 32747, 'clicks': 4184, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)}, datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0): {'impressions': 2159, 'clicks': 223, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0)}}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `dict(sorted(analytics.items()))`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of dict you should use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_dict = OrderedDict()

sorted_keys = sorted(analytics.keys())

for key in sorted_keys:
    ordered_dict.update({key: analytics[key]})
```

see the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict